# html button onclick start javascript progressbar

Tags: javascript, html

Thank you for your quick response i really appriciate it i will put the complete working code underneath for anyone who wishes to use it.

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
    <span id="status"></span>
    <h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
    <button onclick='start(0)'>Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
function start(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al + "%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
  if (al == 100) {
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 100;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
  }
}
var amountLoaded = 0;
//start(amountLoaded);
```

Comment: I just tried the code you've provided and it works - http://jsbin.com/nularicezo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that like this :

```js
function start(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al + "%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
  if (al == 100) {
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 100;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <span id="status"></span>
  <h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
  <!-- Add Button with event Click
  with this event start your progressbar with your function -->
  <button onclick='start(0)'>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry doing it now i saw that it was a copy/paste and as you were the first one to reply with the correct answer i'll chose yours :D

Comment: i did not copy your answere but late in posting answere

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for but take a look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/sLggoyqn/1/

```
<button onClick="start(0);">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code that fill progress bar on click of button

```js
function start(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al + "%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
  if (al == 100) {
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 100;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
    <span id="status"></span>
    <h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
    <button onclick="start(0)">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```